# systemd timer runs more than once per period even with persistent=false

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have a unit that normally I want running, but sometimes I want to manually shut it off for the day and restart it later automatically.  So I have a timer to restart it `OnCalendar=daily`.  This works, but sometimes I need to stop the unit twice because the timer immediately restarts the unit.

Here's a simplified example with minutes instead of days:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo timer

[Timer]
Persistent=false
OnCalendar=minutely
AccuracySec=1
Unit=foo.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

---

```
[Unit]
Description=foo service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

---

If I `systemctl stop foo.service`, and the timer had fired more than 1 minute ago (PASSED > 1m in `systemdctl list-timers`), it immediately refires and starts the unit.  The unit always stays stopped until the next minute if I stop it twice.  The docs make it sound like `Persistent=false` should not cause this, but clearly I'm misunderstanding.  If it matters, the daily unit I'm actually interested in is a system unit, but the test unit is a user unit; the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

`Persistent=false` (i.e. default) keeps disabled the function to catch timers missed during system shutdown. In your case the system is on-line and the timer is omitted - if `OnCalendar` period has passed (likely because foo.service was already running) it still waits for it's moment to be run "a minute/day **after last run**" - not **after last try/check/attempt to be run**, which means exactly *immediately after stop foo.service*.

This is a consequence of, quoting `man systemd.timer`: *Note that in case the unit to activate is already active at the time the timer elapses it is not restarted, but simply left running*. Currently I see no direct way to reset the timer if timer has already elapsed but the action was skipped because of service still running.

The indirect method would be to have <del>self-restarting timer, something like</del> `foo-try_restart.service` <del>invoking `systemctl restart foo-try_restart.timer` before</del> attempting to `systemctl start foo.service`. As your `foo.service` is different from this newly created `foo-try_restart.service` (with `Type=oneshot`, without `RemainAfterExit`) it's `foo-try_restart.timer` would always fire, so it's timer would be reset after each period.